# How to make this MYSQL outer join work

Tags: mysql, join, outer-join

I have 4 tables:

```
comment (CommentID, StoryID, UserID, CommentContent), 
vote (VoteID, UserID, AnswerID), 
answer (AnswerID, StoryID, AnswerContent), 
user (UserID, Username)
```

So I want to get all the comments of story 8 along with the info of the users who make those comments (including their voting information). Not all users who make comments would vote. So this is my query but it didn't work

```
SELECT * FROM comment a 
  LEFT JOIN vote b ON a.UserID = b.UserID 
  JOIN answer c ON b.AnswerID = c.AnswerID 
  JOIN user d ON a.UserId = d.UserID  
GROUP BY a.CommentID HAVING a.StoryID = 8
```

I don't know why this query shows the vote result of commenters who don't vote. Would you please help me to fix it? Thank you so much.

Comment: "didn't work" isn't a very descriptive. Did the query return an error? Return unexpected results? What results were you expecting? The query is going to return a single row per CommentId, because the `GROUP BY CommentId` clause is going to "collapse" all of the vote, answer and user rows into just one row returned for a given `CommentId`. The values returned for the columns from those tables will be from some row in the group, but which row is indeterminate.

Comment: Thank you for your response. One commentator who didn't vote has his vote result show up. His vote result should be null as he didn't vote.

Answer (score 0):

Your GROUP BY and HAVING clauses are incorrect.

```
SELECT * FROM comment a 
  LEFT JOIN vote b ON a.UserID = b.UserID 
  JOIN answer c ON b.AnswerID = c.AnswerID
  WHERE a.StoryID = 8
```

Comment: If you want all users regardless of if they've post a comment you'll want to use a 'RIGHT JOIN' to the 'user' table. Missing values will appear as NULL.